# kde inside ubuntu install

Tags: installation, usb, kubuntu, kde

I am using Ubuntu with KDE-full desktop now. I want install it for my friends computers too. So installing KDE-full as long as Ubuntu installs, it would help me.
I want have an install usb, that contains KDE inside. I can install Ubuntu with USB, then  installing KDE-full with commands in terminal. But I need KDE inside Ubuntu version (Like as Kde inside Mint). 
How can I provide Ubuntu version that have KDE as predefined Desktop and have KDE apps in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get exactly what you need but I'll recommend downloading kubuntu (http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu ) and then use the start up disk creator included in ubuntu to create a bootable live cd from which you'll be able to install ubuntu with KDE desktop and apps directly.
Best,

Answer (score 1):

I believe the command `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` would get you the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of having understood your question, but if you are so happy with KDE experience that you want to use it in other computers, I would recommend you to install [kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org) 
which is an official (yet unmantained by Canonical) ubuntu community-driven distribution. You can download kubuntu from http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu and copy the image into a USB or CD, boot a computer and use the installator, just exactly as you would do with a regular ubuntu image.

The difference (and the good thing of installing it) is that it comes with full KDE experience (KDE plasma, desktop and apps) and without unity nor gtk apps. This method has the following key advantages (in my opinion):

1. Coherent KDE experience (if you install KDE on top of unity you may see light DM for login instead of lightkdm, or your default apps will be ubuntu's instead of KDE's, for example)
2. You won't have any duplicate apps (if you install KDE on top of unity you will have nautilus and dolphin as filemanagers, empathy and telepathy as IM clients -in my experience they don't seem to get on well together- and so on) and you will save some space and remove redundancy.
3. And of course no need to "waste" time in intermediate steps which are not necessary.